# How to implement something similar to FlowRow in JetpackCompose

Tags: list, android-jetpack-compose, row

I'm creating an Android App using Jetpack Compose. I'm stuck on the list of interests. When one item can't be placed in the first row it should go to the second row. I know there was something like FlowRow, but now it is depracated. Any way to do this now?[image]

Comment: LazyVerticalGrid

Comment: With the FlowRow provided by the accompanist library https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find FlowRow it in the [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/) utils for Jetpack Compose: [FlowRow](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/)

Update: If you are using Jetpack Compose version 1.4.0+ it has official FlowLayouts in `androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*` package. Here is the [release info](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/03/whats-new-in-jetpack-compose-march-23-release.html)